# Terminate server thread on timeout

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I copied this code from a tutorial. It starts a new thread every time a new TCP connection is made.

```
require 'socket'                # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open(2000)   # Socket to listen on port 2000
loop {                          # Servers run forever
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.puts(Time.now.ctime) # Send the time to the client
    client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
    client.close                # Disconnect from the client
  end
}
```

It's working well, but now I would like to terminate the thread in the case of a timeout. To do this, I need to terminate the thread (I can't just throw an exception, because I have to have `abort_on_exception` enabled so that debugging is easy), but I can't figure out how to get the thread handle.

I feel like I should be able to something like this in the loop:

```
Thread.start(server.accept) do |client, myThread|
    begin
        Timeout::timeout(1) do
            #important stuff
        end
    rescue Timeout::Error
        client.puts "Timeout"
        client.close
        myThread.terminate
    end
end
```

I also can't replace `myThread.terminate` with `exit` because that kills my main process (for reasons I don't entirely understand) and I don't want the server to stop running because the last thread is terminated.

Comment: It should be noted that if you ever have to make a multi-threaded server, it's probably just easier to use `eventmachine`.

Comment: I've asked another question in regards to my main process being kill by `exit`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604866/why-does-exiting-a-ruby-thread-kill-my-whole-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Thread.current.terminate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-current)

Comment: From what I understand from the documentation, wouldn't that just put my thread to sleep? I don't want it hanging around and taking up memory until I end my program.

Comment: Ah ok, I see your problem You are right, without joining the thread it will remain in a sleep state. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's strange. I didn't expect there to be a difference in behavior between `Thread.current.terminate` and just calling `exit`. Would you care to elaborate why or point to where I can determine this for myself in the documentation?

Comment: Turns out that when I was calling `exit`, I was calling `Kernel#exit` which is why my program was terminating.