# Why does exiting a Ruby thread kill my whole program?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have this piece of code:

```
puts "Start"
loop do
    Thread.start do
        puts "Hello from thread"
        exit
    end
    text = gets
    puts "#{text}"
end
puts "Done"
```

What I would expect is seeing "Start" followed by "Hello from thread" and then I could enter input that would get echoed back to me. Instead I get "Start" and "Hello from thread" and then the program exits.

From the documentation on `exit`:

> Terminates thr and schedules another thread to be run. If this thread
>   is already marked to be killed, exit returns the Thread. If this is
>   the main thread, or the last thread, exits the process.

But I thought I spawned a new thread? Why is it exiting my main process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking at the [`Thread#exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-i-exit) documentation. `kill` is [`Kernel#exit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) which terminates the Ruby script.

```
puts "Start"
loop do
    Thread.start do
        puts "Hello from thread"
        Thread.exit
    end
    text = gets
    puts "#{text}"
end
puts "Done"
```